# create a set expression for a cell in a table report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, dynamics-crm-online

I have a report which creates a spreadsheet. one cell could have data from one of three fields depending on a fourth field status or field two being blank..

I was thinking of writing as CASE statement but that does not work in ssrs.

The IIF statement works great for 2 values but how do you write for three values?

In common language it would be "If secondary value ="Yes", use secondary name, If account field value is Null, use Contact field value, otherwise use account field value"

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use nested IIF statements but they quickly get messy. You should use SWITCH which acts a bit like a case statement.

A simple example would be

```
= SWITCH(
    Fields!myFirstField.Value = <10 , "Small",
    Fields!myFirstField.Value = <30 , "Medium",
    Fields!myFirstField.Value = <80 , "Large",
    True , "HUGE",
    )
```

As switch stops at the first true expression there is not need to check ranges of values if you get them in the correct order.

The final "True" expression just acts like an ELSE

If you need to check multiple criteria per condition then you can do that too like this..

```
= SWITCH(
    Fields!myFirstField.Value = <10 AND Fields!mySecondField.Value = 1 , "Small Cat",
    Fields!myFirstField.Value = <10 AND Fields!mySecondField.Value = 2 , "Small Dog",
    Fields!myFirstField.Value = <30 , "Medium Animal",
    Fields!myFirstField.Value = <80 , "Large Animal",
    True , "HUGE Animal",
    )
```